# Pass value from JavaScript to BackingBean

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I think this question has been asked before but I still don't understand how to do it. My objective is to click on a point in GoogleMaps and store the coordinates of the point I clicked on a backing bean. My code is as following:

JSF

```
<h:inputHidden id="lat"         value="#{ChartsBean.lat}" />
<p:commandLink id="updateChart" update="chart" actionListener="#{ChartsBean.lineChart}"/>
<p:lineChart   id="chart"       value="#{ChartsBean.lineChart}" />
```

JS

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    document.getElementById('lat').value = '99': //just for testing
    $("#updateChart").click();
});
```

BackingBean

```
private String       lat,lon;
//getters and setters
```

The element 'lat' is getting its value correctly setted but the changes don't seem to reach the backing bean.

But the updateChart is working. I didn't post it here but on the bean if I have:

**EDIT1:** 
Another thing, if on my backing bean I set the X and Y like this:

```
x = (int)(20*Math.random());
y = (int)(20*Math.random());
```

Instead of:

```
x = findX(Double.parseDouble(lat));
y = findY(Double.parseDouble(lon));
```

The chart is refeshed when I click anywhere on the maps, obvioulsy to a random point.

Comment: What does you mean `the changes don't seem to reach the backing bean` while `The element 'lat' is getting its value correctly setted` ?

Comment: The value of the variable lat on my backing bean is always null, although the value of the variable lat on JS is indeed correct (99 on this example)

Answer (score 1):

Basically your problem is that `$("#updateChart")` wont work since the real button ID include the `h:form` ID (prepend). You can fix that by changing your `h:form` attribute `prependId="false"`.

**Warning :**

Disabling prepend on the form will prevent the hability to use same IDs inside each forms.

**Another way** is to add some class to your link :

```
<p:commandLink id="updateChart" class="some-unique-class" update="chart" actionListener="#{ChartsBean.lineChart}"/>
```

And change your selector :

```
$("a.some-unique-class").click();
```

One **last solution** that I forgot, still the best I think when using jQuery :

```
$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{p:component('updateChart')}')).click();
```

**More info :**

- [PrimeFaces p:component](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/component.fn.html)

**Read also :**

- [PrimeFaces p:remoteCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) really useful if you want to only send data to bean without buttons

Comment: But the updateChart is working. I added more info to the main post.

Comment: @te-x But when you click on the map, the bean is not updated right?

Comment: Thats right. The variables on the JS are working correctly, and I can request a new chart from the backing bean. I just can't tell it which chart to draw.

Comment: `$("#updateChart").click();` will never work, that's why your backing bean doesn't get anything. Also I doubt that your hidden input get the value 99, can you test in firebug?

Comment: If I do something like var test = document.getElementById('lat').value; the value is correct. And why can't $(#updateChart").click() not work if the chart is being refreshed?

Comment: @te-x `#{ChartsBean.lineChart}` get called in the bean?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understood your question. But the in bean I have a getLineChart() that uses the values of lat and lon to generate a chart. If I use random values, the chart returned and correctly displayed, but both lat and lon on the bean are always and, as such, can't be used to generate the new chart. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's relevant, but all this components are not inside a form. Just inside a <td>

Comment: I didn't knew that. I now have a <h:form id"charts" prependId="false> and the inputHidden,commandLink and LineChart inside it. However, my charts no longer update when I click on the map.

Comment: But the value of lat is now arriving to the bean. The only problem now seems to be the chart not updating.

Comment: @te-x No errors in server output? Validation or conversion errors?

Comment: Thanks a lot! (it was another <h:form> missing)
I've been trying to fix this for a week. I've absolutely no experience with this technology. Again, thanks!

Comment: @te-x You are welcome, I suggest you to read some of BalusC blog : http://balusc.blogspot.ca/ this is very good stuff, also he answer marjority of JSF questions here, check his profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc

Comment: I read a post on his blog about this yesterday, that I found through google. It didn't solve my problem but I liked the blog.